# Tips for modifying the python web scraping code using functions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, execution-time

I'm trying to write a python script using BeautifulSoup that crawls through a webpage http://tbc-python.fossee.in/completed-books/ and collects necessary data from it. Basically it has to fetch all the `page loading errors, SyntaxErrors, NameErrors, AttributeErrors, etc` present in the chapters of all the books to a text file `errors.txt`. There are around 273 books. The script written is doing the task well. I am using bandwidth with good speed. But the code takes much time to scrape through all the books. Please help me to optimize the python script with necessary tweaks, maybe use of functions, etc. Thanks

```
import urllib2, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website = "http://tbc-python.fossee.in/completed-books/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(website))
errors = open('errors.txt','w')

# Completed books webpage has data stored in table format
BookTable = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered table-hover'})
for BookCount, BookRow in enumerate(BookTable.find_all('tr'), start = 1):
    # Grab  book names
    BookCol = BookRow.find_all('td')
    BookName = BookCol[1].a.string.strip()
    print "%d: %s" % (BookCount, BookName)  
    # Open each book
    BookSrc = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' %(BookCol[1].a.get("href"))))
    ChapTable = BookSrc.find('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered table-hover'})

    # Check if each chapter page opens, if not store book & chapter name in error.txt
    for ChapRow in ChapTable.find_all('tr'):
        ChapCol = ChapRow.find_all('td')
        ChapName = (ChapCol[0].a.string.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore') # ignores error : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef'
        ChapLink = 'http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' %(ChapCol[0].a.get("href"))

        try:
            ChapSrc = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(ChapLink))
        except:
            print '\t%s\n\tPage error' %(ChapName)
            errors.write("Page; %s;%s;%s;%s" %(BookCount, BookName, ChapName, ChapLink))
            continue

        # Check for errors in chapters and store the errors in error.txt
        EgError = ChapSrc.find_all('div', {'class': 'output_subarea output_text output_error'})
        if EgError:
            for e, i in enumerate(EgError, start=1):
                errors.write("Example;%s;%s;%s;%s\n" %(BookCount,BookName,ChapName,ChapLink)) if 'ipython-input' or 'Error' in i.pre.get_text() else None           
            print '\t%s\n\tExample errors: %d' %(ChapName, e)       

errors.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and spiting the workload.

Your connection speed doesn't matter much if you're only using 1 connection at a time.

Comment: @ OneOfOne . I am using 1 connection at a time. Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @ThirumaleshHS I don't see a way to make it faster without splitting it up, but maybe someone else will. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to break up the code and represented it using functions.
Any suggestions to improvise the code again? How to dump the errors fetched from the website into a new html file with a table format having the details of the books and chapters that contains errors.

Below is the updated code:

```
import urllib2, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(link, index):
    """
    This function takes in two arguments and returns a list which contains details of 
    books and/or chapters like:
    * name of the book or chapter
    * link of the book or chapter

    Getting details from book or chapter is set by index value
    * index = 1 --> gets details of the book
    * index = 0 --> gets details of the chapter
    """
    details_list = []

    src = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(link))
    table = src.find('table')
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        column = row.find_all('td')  
        name, link = column[index].a.string, column[index].a.get("href")
        details_list.append([name, link])

    return details_list


def get_chapter_errors(chap_link):
    """
    This function takes in chapter link from chapter_details_list as argument and returns 
    * Number of example errors(SyntaxErrors, NameErrors, ValueErrors, etc) present in the chapter
                 OR
    * HTTPError while loading the chapter
    """
    try:
        chp_src = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(chap_link))
        example_errors = chp_src.find_all('div', {'class': 'output_subarea output_text output_error'})
        error = len(example_errors)
        if not example_errors:
            error = None 

    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        print e
        error = "Page fetch error"

    return error


def main():
    log_dict = {}
    book_dict = {}

    url = sys.argv[1] # accept url as argument
    book_details_list = get_details(url, index=1)
    for book_name, book_link in book_details_list:
        chapter_details_list = get_details('http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' % book_link, index=0)
        _id = book_link.strip('/book-details')
        book_dict = {'name': book_name,
                     'url': 'http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' % book_link,
                     'id': _id,
                     'chapters': []
                    }

        for chap_name, chap_link in chapter_details_list:
            error = get_chapter_errors('http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' % chap_link)
            book_dict.get('chapters').append({'name': chap_name, 
                                              'url': 'http://tbc-python.fossee.in%s' % chap_link, 
                                              'errors': error
                                             })

        log_dict.update({_id: book_dict})

        print log_dict
        print "\n\n\n\n"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```